# Velocity not finding method

Tags: java, velocity

I'm working on a webapp, using Apache Velocity as the template engine. I want it to show a HTML5 select, as shown below.

```
<select class="form-control" id="detailFunction">
    #foreach($function in $functions)
    <option id="$function.getId()">$function.getTitle()</option>
    #end
</select>
```

My `Function` class looks like this:

```
package com.stackoverflow;
class Function {
    private final int id;
    private final String title;

    Function(int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

`$functions` is a `List<Function>`. However, when I run this code, it says:

```
Object 'com.stackoverflow.Function' does not contain method getId() at /velocity/editor.vm[line 40, column 48]
```

while it's clearly there. Even changing `$functions` to the `Function[]` type does not change a thing. What could this be?

Comment: Do a completely clean build?

Comment: Did `mvn clean && mvn compile` a couple of times already.

Comment: Maybe it should return string

Comment: @SeanF I got the same error when `getId()` was removed from the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `public` access modifier to Function class so [Velocity](https://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityFAQ) will be able to use it

> Velocity will only allow public methods on public classes to be called for security reasons.

Declare your class:

```
 public class Function {
```

It's not mandatory, but you probably should add your constructor also the public access if you will need it in velocity template

```
 public Function(int id, String title) {
```

Comment: The constructor does not need to be `public` in this context.

Comment: @WardSegers yes, but if you will need it in different velocity context? I'll update that it's not mandatory for this question